# Integrating DHTML scheduler calendar in phonegap application

Tags: jquery, mobile, cordova, dhtml

When I try to load scheduler calendar in my phonegap application first time it is displaying the correct data what i really want , but when i come back to other page and try to load different data the calendar is not refreshing properly. It is displaying the old data according to the old Id.It is not parsing the data for new id .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can put the call to calendar on the "pageshow" method on your javascript file, like:

`$page.on('pageshow', function(){`
`showCalendar();`
`})`